# How to find the white pixels between two points in an edge image using matlab?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have edges from an image, In edge image I have two points , I want to count the no of white pixels between these two points . Intent is to count the white pixels and if it greater than certain threshold than call this edge as potential edge to form square.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNIcv.jpg)
In Image I have 2 points X1, Y1 and X2, Y2, and I want to count the no pixels. These X1, Y1 and X2,Y2 points can have anywhere else like leftmost or upper most etc.

Comment: How would you like to count white pixels, in a row, in a column or white pixels in a connected component? please explain. Well, you can use `regionprops()` to find the FilledArea of connected component in matlab and  `contourArea()` function in openCV

Comment: Not in connected components.  I want to find white pixels between two points  as in  example. These two points can be anywhere in the image . Can along row or columns. Only given input is two points.

Comment: then loop over specific row/column and count pixels i.e. `if (img[row,col] == 255) count = count + 1`